# jpackage --type app-image creates infinite recursive directories

Tags: jpackage

I'm trying to use `jpackage` to create an installer for my Java app.  I'm on Windows 10 using OpenJDK 15.0.1.  I can build an installer using

```
jpackage --input C:\MyApp --main-jar MyApp.jar
```

This basically works, but the installed application lacks resource files.  According to the documentation, I should be able to build an app image, add my resource files to the image, then build the installer from the modified app image, as follows

```
jpackage --type app-image -n MyAppImage
copy <resource files> MyAppImage
jpackage --app-image MyAppImage --name MyAppInstaller
```

However, when I try `jpackage --type app-image` the process never terminates, and I have to kill it with control-C.  When I examine the `MyAppImage` directory, it has a subdirectory `app`, which more or less mirrors the contents of `C:\MyApp`.  Those contents include `MyAppImage`, which recursively gets copied into the `app` subdirectory, creating a potentially infinite set of directories: `C:\MyApp\MyAppImage\app\MyAppImage\app\MyAppImage` ...

If I manually delete `app\MyAppImage` and try `jpackage --app-image`, jpackage crashes with a java.io.IOException.

Has anyone else encountered this?  What should I try?

Comment: Also came across this horrible bug. Was unable to delete it using any windows tools, had to use a Linux shell emulator run the rm tool to delete everything.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the shell working directory makes a difference.  The directory specified by --input should not be the same as the directory where the app image will be created.

I fixed the problem by creating a subdirectory C:\MyApp\build and copying
MyApp.jar to build.

```
cd C:\MyApp
mkdir build
copy MyApp.jar build
jpackage --type app-image --n MyAppImage --input C:\MyApp\build --main-jar MyApp.jar
```

The recursive file-copying doesn't happen any more.  But I'm still getting an error when running `jpackage --app-image`.  I'll make that the subject of a subsequent post.

Comment: Same solution, but instead of copying the file manually, I have used the one created by `mvn install` under `~/.m2/repository/mylib/myapp/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT`